# API to download dependencies from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to write a java program that takes a maven pom.xml file as input and does following:

1. Downloads all dependencies
2. Adds jars to classpath
3. Executes java code (loaded from the jars)

Is it possible? any sample code to achieve #1 above will be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's exactly what Maven does - Is it not possible to let `mvn` do this for you?

Comment: Right on... do you really need to re-implement mvn? If you need to embed the functionality in your app, you could try including some Maven source code since it's an open source project. Alternatively, if Maven's installed, you could simply call `mvn` in a shell.

Comment: Maven is open source - download the code and see how they do it^^

Comment: take a look at [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/), which will help you with step #1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you absolutely have to do this embeded in a Java app:**

The library Maven uses under the covers to do dependency resolution is called Aether. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) on the Sonatype site there's an example of how to do step 1. Part of the dependency resolution process will give you access to a list of dependencies which you can then loop over to build your classpath.

For step 3 you could use a ProcessBuilder and launch the target Java app as a subprocess of the JVM that used Aether to build the classpath.

**If you can use a shell script:**

You can use `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=[group]:[artifact]:[version]` to download the artifacts to your local repo.

Then you can use `mvn dependency:build-classpath` to generate the classpath string.

Then you can simply execute java with a -cp option. You'd have to also know what main class you want is, or you could compute the name of the primary jar from the artifact and version number and pass that to -jar.

**If you're able to get the pom.xml of the main project in your deployment environment:**

You can just use `mvn exec:java -DmainClass=com.company.package.YourMainClass`. This option is by far the simplest, but it does have the downside of executing within the maven JVM and as far as I've been able to find out there's no option for forking a separate process. Also you need to have a full fledged pom to make this work which isn't always convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Your requirements are exactly what the [Maven Exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) already does.

Comment: Our requirements are to leverage maven functionality fomr a java program. Mojo if i am not mistaken allows to execute java from Maven.